# Передать переменные окружения в докер контейнер

Tags: docker, jenkins

Есть jenkins-job (не pipeline), которая тянет из гита код, собирает его и запускает в докер контейнере. Мне нужно передать в контейнер переменные окружения (желательно из файла). Я перепробовал все варианты, которые нашел в интернете, но не помогло.
Вот текст jenkins job:

```
cp WL/${stageid}/env_settings.env ./env_settings.env
ls

docker build \
   -t customer_front${stagePrefix} . 
docker stop customer_front${stagePrefix} || true && docker rm 
   customer_front${stagePrefix} || true
#source env_settings.env
docker run \
  -d --restart unless-stopped \
  -e CLIENT_URL='https://test.customer.app' \
  -e SITE_NAME='My best site' \
  --name customer_front${stagePrefix} \
  -p ${externalPort}:3000 \
  customer_front${stagePrefix}
```

Это последняя версия файла, где я пытался передать аргументы хотя бы через параметр `-e`. Пробовал передавать `--env-file env_settings.env` (я качаю этот файл в первой строке job'ы), но и это не прокатило.
Вот dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12-alpine

#ARG API_CLIENT_URL
#ARG API_SITE_NAME=MySite

#ENV CLIENT_URL=$API_CLIENT_URL
ENV SITE_NAME

RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add git

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

RUN ls

COPY . .

RUN ls
RUN npm run build

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Если во время сборки сделать (при раскомментированных аргументах и переменных в dockerfile) `docker build  --build-arg API_CLIENT_URL=https://test.customer.app`, то я могу достучаться до `API_CLIENT_URL`, но мне не подходит вариант делать это все во время сборки, нужно во время запуска и желательно из файла.
Если кто-то заметил, что я делаю не так или знает как решить проблему, поделитесь опытом, пожалуйста

Comment: `-e` или `--env` записывают переданные переменные среды в самой системе контейнера. Так же есть ключ `--env-file`  - записывает в переменные окружения все данные из файла. Т.е. остается эти переменные обработать самим приложением: Получить из переменных окружений, подставить куда нужно

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что я не могу получить к ним доступ из приложения, которое работает в контейнере. А если я из докерфайла присваиваю им значения из аргументов сборки, то работает.

Comment: Не совсем так, эти переменные окружения как раз и будут внутри контейнера с собранным приложением, а не в ОС, на которой контейнер запущен. Как вариант, запустите контейнер с параметром `-e  CLIENT_URL='https://test.customer.app'`, подключитесь к контейнеру через `docker exec ...` и проверьте `echo $CLIENT_URL`

Answer (score 1):

> нужно во время запуска и желательно из файла

согласно документации к команде `run`, [можно использовать](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) такие опции:

```
$ docker run -e var1=значение1 --env var2=значение2 ...

$ export var1=значение1
$ export var2=значение2
$ docker run --env var1 -e var2 ...

$ cat файл.с.переменными
var1=значение1
var2=значение2
$ docker run --env-file файл.с.переменными ...
```

во всех трёх вариантах вызова команды `run` процесс в контейнере получит две переменных окружения — `var1` и `var2` (со значениями `значение1` и `значение2`).

---

для вашего случая, вероятно, подойдёт вариант два, где опциями перечисляются лишь имена передаваемых переменных, а значения для них берутся из соответствующих переменных окружения процесса, в котором выполняется команда `run`.